# Setting div height dynamically in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a requirement wherein based on some variable values in component, I either need to show a button or not. In case button is to be shown, parent div height would be more than div height when button is not to be shown.

I have heights of div in pixels for both cases. But whether button is to be shown or not is decided dynamically, hence I can hard code div height in css.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Maybe it'll be helpful if you share *some* code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle), based on value of `show` that can be true or false:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'height': show ? '10px' : '100px' }"></<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button id="myBtn">hello</button> 

 #myBtn{  
       display: block;
 }

 var element = document.getElementById('myBtn'),
     style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
     isShow = style.getPropertyValue('display');
```

You can control the display value of button.